# Trailing "r" on serialized JSON string

Tags: json, ajax

I am getting a trailing "r" character on a serialized json string returned to an ajax call. I am using the exact same code on three other pages and it works fine. PLEASE HELP!!

```
  $.ajax({
            url: '../GroupDiv/GroupHistory.aspx', 
            method: 'get',
            data: { GroupID: GrpIdNbr, CompanyID: CoIdNbr, StartDate: effDt, EndDate: trmDt },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {...
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, err) {...
```

GroupHistory.aspx

```
Private Class History
            Public addr_line_1 As String
            Public addr_line_2 As String
            Public addr_csz As String
            Public addr_phone_nbr As String
            Public addr_eff_dt As String
            Public addr_trm_dt As String
            Public addr_type_cd As String
        End Class
      //...
      Dim histories As New List(Of History)
      //...fill histories list works fine

    Response.Clear()
    Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(histories))
    //json string serialized here looks fine, parses fine

    //Ajax catches error NOTE the trailing "r"
     SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 188 of 
     the JSON data

     [{"addr_line_1":"123 W Main","addr_line_2":"","addr_csz":"ANYWHERE, AR 
     70000","addr_phone_nbr":"","addr_eff_dt":"1901-01-01","addr_trm_dt":"9999-12- 
     31","addr_type_cd":"P"}]r

//XHR status comes back 200: OK
//Caught err status is parsererror
```

UPDATE: The ajax call is is on one page (GroupDetail.aspx), calls to the other page (GroupHistory.aspx). The request from GroupDetail.aspx ajax looks like this: https://localhost/csw/GroupDiv/GroupHistory.aspx?GroupID=080890&CompanyID=U&StartDate=1/1/2010&EndDate=12/31/9999

Request values query database, fill in the histories list the serialize the response back to  GroupDetail.aspx ajax

Comment: The request you show and the result you show don't seem to be related to each other. That `$.ajax` call definitely won't send a string with a trailing `r` on it unless something has mucked with `$.ajax` or `JSON.stringify` or similar on the page (unlikely, but you can check in your devtools network panel to see what was sent).

Comment: Look at the network tab in your browser. Does the outgoing request already have that `r`?

Comment: Added update. Checked the request object, no trailing "r". Checked the json on the GroupHistory (data generating page) no trailing "r". Something is happening between the serialize on one page and the ajax promise resolve on the other page GroupDetail.